# how to read the content of an FTP file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ftp, spring-integration

I am using spring integration, and I am creating a file manager using ftp Integration in spring. I have managed to create a file browser as such

```
@Configuration
public class FtpConfiguration {
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpLS")
    @Bean
    public FtpOutboundGateway getGW() {
        FtpOutboundGateway gateway = new FtpOutboundGateway(sf(), "ls", "payload");
        gateway.setOption(Option.SUBDIRS);
        gateway.setOutputChannelName("results");
        return gateway;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel results() {
        DirectChannel channel = new DirectChannel();
        return channel;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost("localhost");
        sf.setPort(21);
        sf.setUsername("admin");
        sf.setPassword("admin");
        return sf;
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "ftpLS", defaultReplyChannel = "results")
    public interface Gate {
        List<FtpFileInfo> list(String directory);
    }

    @Bean
    public FtpRemoteFileTemplate template(DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf) {
        return new FtpRemoteFileTemplate(sf);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to  read a file, and also create or delete a new file using spring integration. I am very new to this. Any help would be appreciated.
I tried using the File Buffered reader

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

but the root of the file searches for the file in my local directory, is there a way to point it to the ftp, and also the ftp and username and password as mentioned in my above spring integration configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn’t fully clear, but read, create, delete are also possible via that `FtpOutboundGateway`. See its `command` option: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway

Comment: i want to read the content of the file, without downloading it in my local directory. and create a file in the ftp server, and that too when a user matched a request in RequestMapping("/something")

Comment: i read the documents , but i want to set the Option of the ftpoutboundgateway to be SUBDIRS , so how is it possible to read, the files?

Comment: SUBDIRS is for the `ls` command. To read files content you will need to iterate a result of that Gateway and call a new one with `get` command.